# Using services. calling service

Tags: ros, rosservice, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I want to call a service from node cpp file.
is it possible?

I want to create my own node and use a service from another package.
what is the aim of [ros::service::call](http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/doc/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1service.html#a33d9fb0f32ff8bbac4db4188d657715d)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12779/using-services.-calling-service./) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2012-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-02-09**:
The tutorial contains an example showing how to call a service with a service proxy. Look at 1.2 Writing the Client Node. If you really need to use ros::service::call, replace the client.call(srv) by ros::service::call("add_two_ints, srv).

**Comment by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on 2012-02-09**:
thanks, but i need at least one example!